# Why am I receiving "creation of NFT errored: Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }" in my remix.eth. code?

Tags: blockchain, remix, nft

I am trying to publish my collection of 5,000 NFTs and I'm just about to upload them to Opensea... I just keep receiving the error in the title. I had no problem producing 1, 20, or 50 NFTs of the 5000. But when I changed the number to 5000, for some reason I get this error. Does anyone know what's wrong? Appreciate any feedback :)

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract NFT is ERC721Enumerable, Ownable {
  using Strings for uint256;

  string public baseURI;
  string public baseExtension = ".json";
  uint256 public cost = 0.05 ether;
  uint256 public maxSupply = 10000;
  uint256 public maxMintAmount = 5000;
  bool public paused = false;
  mapping(address => bool) public whitelisted;

  constructor(
    string memory _name,
    string memory _symbol,
    string memory _initBaseURI
  ) ERC721(_name, _symbol) {
    setBaseURI(_initBaseURI);
    mint(msg.sender, 5000);
  }

  // internal
  function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory) {
    return baseURI;
  }

  // public
  function mint(address _to, uint256 _mintAmount) public payable {
    uint256 supply = totalSupply();
    require(!paused);
    require(_mintAmount > 0);
    require(_mintAmount <= maxMintAmount);
    require(supply + _mintAmount <= maxSupply);

    if (msg.sender != owner()) {
        if(whitelisted[msg.sender] != true) {
          require(msg.value >= cost * _mintAmount);
        }
    }

    for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++) {
      _safeMint(_to, supply + i);
    }
  }

  function walletOfOwner(address _owner)
    public
    view
    returns (uint256[] memory)
  {
    uint256 ownerTokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);
    uint256[] memory tokenIds = new uint256[](ownerTokenCount);
    for (uint256 i; i < ownerTokenCount; i++) {
      tokenIds[i] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_owner, i);
    }
    return tokenIds;
  }

  function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
    public
    view
    virtual
    override
    returns (string memory)
  {
    require(
      _exists(tokenId),
      "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token"
    );

    string memory currentBaseURI = _baseURI();
    return bytes(currentBaseURI).length > 0
        ? string(abi.encodePacked(currentBaseURI, tokenId.toString(), baseExtension))
        : "";
  }

  //only owner
  function setCost(uint256 _newCost) public onlyOwner() {
    cost = _newCost;
  }

  function setmaxMintAmount(uint256 _newmaxMintAmount) public onlyOwner() {
    maxMintAmount = _newmaxMintAmount;
  }

  function setBaseURI(string memory _newBaseURI) public onlyOwner {
    baseURI = _newBaseURI;
  }

  function setBaseExtension(string memory _newBaseExtension) public onlyOwner {
    baseExtension = _newBaseExtension;
  }

  function pause(bool _state) public onlyOwner {
    paused = _state;
  }

 function whitelistUser(address _user) public onlyOwner {
    whitelisted[_user] = true;
  }

  function removeWhitelistUser(address _user) public onlyOwner {
    whitelisted[_user] = false;
  }

  function withdraw() public payable onlyOwner {
    (bool success, ) = payable(msg.sender).call{value: address(this).balance}("");
    require(success);
  }
}
```

Comment: i used the same tutorial has you and i have the same issue, i think the tutorial is flawed

Answer (score 1):

my guess would be that you're hitting this require statement
`require(supply + _mintAmount <= maxSupply);`, what are you doing exactly? calling the `mint` function with your address and 5000 as arguments?
Or are you just trying to deploy the contract? if so you're probably hitting the gas limit

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry, though, I am new to this all... kinda following a tutorial video. What exactly do you recommend I do so I can get all 5000 uploaded to Opensea?

Comment: Are you trying to deploy this contract or  is it already deployed and you're trying to mint additionnal tokens using the `mint` function?

Comment: I am trying to deploy it with the 5000 nfts... still learning how to mint additional ones